# No errors , but no output in console from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image]

I'm trying to build an extension to monitor the xhr portion of the devtools network tab.  I decided to start as simple as possible with the background script below. I'm seeing no errors on loading the extension, but don't see any output in the console.

manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"version": "1.0",
"name": "Hello World!",
"description": "Learning how to make a chrome extension!",
"icons": {
    "16": "images/puppy16.png",
    "48": "images/puppy48.png",
    "128": "images/puppy128.png"
},
"action": {
    "default_icon": "images/puppy.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"host_permissions": [
    "https://yahoo.com/*"
],
"permissions": [
    "webRequest"
]
}
```

In my background.js:

```
(function () {

    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
        function (details) {
            console.log('HELLO THERE!!!!', details);
        },
        { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }
    );

}());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which console are you trying to log to? just to clarify,`background.js` logs to the background page console, not the webpage console

Comment: OK, did not Know that. I was thinking as a test the webpage console.

Comment: Nope, they are separate. Here's an answer that can help you view the background console: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/accessing-console-and-devtools-of-extensions-background-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background-page and webpage console log to different places so you wouldn't see `console.log('HELLO THERE!!!!', details);` in the webpage's console. Refer the answer below for how to view the background-page console.

[Accessing console and devtools of extension's background.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/accessing-console-and-devtools-of-extensions-background-js)